# How to produce simple html readable format of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

With a pandas dataframe such as this:

[image]

I would like to produce a string viewable in html format like this:

```
A: alfa 1, alfa 2
B: beta 1, beta 2
```

Which means that my actual string would have to look something like:

```
'A: alfa info 1, alfa info 2<br>B beta info 1 beta info 2'
```

I'd like to accomplish this with a nested list comprehension, and I've tried variatons of:

```
[[c + ': ' + r for r in df[c]] for c in df.columns]
```

Which gives:

```
[['A: alfa 1', 'A: alfa 2'], ['B: beta 1', 'B: beta 2']]
```

I'm unable to get the `c` component 'outside' the list with row values, and in any case I'm a bit lost on how to get to the next step of *unlisting* these items into a string.

I'm a bit surprised that there's no built-in way to do this, since numerous other string-related methods exist like `df.do_dict`, `df.to_string` and `df.to_html`, none of which returns the desired output.

Thank you for any suggestions!

#### Reproducible example

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': ['alfa 1', 'alfa 2'],
                 'B': ['beta 1', 'beta 2']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.to_dict('list')` will return a dict with column name as key and the rows as a list of values.

```py
>>> df.to_dict('list')
{'A': ['alfa 1', 'alfa 2'], 'B': ['beta 1', 'beta 2']}
```

From there, we can use dict comphrehension along with `str.join` to get the expected output:

```py
>>> '<br>'.join(f"{key}: {', '.join(data)}" for key, data in df.to_dict('list').items())
'A: alfa 1, alfa 2<br>B: beta 1, beta 2'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
[['A: alfa 1', 'A: alfa 2'], ['B: beta 1', 'B: beta 2']]
```

you might use `.join` twice to get single `str` as follows

```
data = [['A: alfa 1', 'A: alfa 2'], ['B: beta 1', 'B: beta 2']]
data = [','.join(i) for i in data]
data = '<br>'.join(data)
print(data)
```

output

```
A: alfa 1,A: alfa 2<br>B: beta 1,B: beta 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Most straight-forward approach is to transpose the `DataFrame` and then use [`DataFrame.to_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': ['alfa 1', 'alfa 2'],
                 'B': ['beta 1', 'beta 2']})

df = df.transpose()
df.to_html('test.html', header=False, border=0)
```

Note, this will produce `table` with border 0

```
<table border="0" class="dataframe">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <td>alfa 1</td>
      <td>alfa 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>B</th>
      <td>beta 1</td>
      <td>beta 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Of course you can use different name for transposed `DataFrame`, or rename columns to include colon if it is mandatory.

**EDIT:** I missed the comma in the desired representation. If necessary, you can create new column for that

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': ['alfa 1', 'alfa 2'],
                 'B': ['beta 1', 'beta 2']})

df = df.transpose()
df['html'] = df.apply(lambda x:', '.join(x.astype(str)),1)
df.to_html('test.html', header=False, border=0, columns=['html'])
```

now the output is

```
<table border="0" class="dataframe">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <td>alfa 1, alfa 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>B</th>
      <td>beta 1, beta 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below works

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['alfa 1', 'alfa 2'],
                   'B': ['beta 1', 'beta 2']})

output = '<br>'.join([c + ' ' + ': '.join(r for r in df[c]) for c in df.columns])
print(output)
```

output

```
A alfa 1: alfa 2<br>B beta 1: beta 2
```